# Rewrite UDF to pandas udf with ArrayType column

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to rewrite an UDF into pandas UDF.

However when it comes to the column with ArrayType inside. I am struggling to find the right solution.

I have a dataframe as below:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|      genre|                 ids|
+-----------+--------------------+
|      Crime|[6, 22, 42, 47, 5...|
|    Romance|[3, 7, 11, 15, 17...|
|   Thriller|[6, 10, 16, 18, 2...|
|  Adventure|[2, 8, 10, 15, 29...|
|   Children|[1, 2, 8, 13, 34,...|
|      Drama|[4, 11, 14, 16, 1...|
|        War|[41, 110, 151, 15...|
|Documentary|[37, 77, 99, 108,...|
|    Fantasy|[2, 56, 60, 126, ...|
|    Mystery|[59, 113, 123, 16...|
+-----------+--------------------+
```

The following UDF works well:

```
pairs_udf = udf(lambda x: itertools.combinations(x, 2), transformer.schema)
df = df.select("genre", pairs_udf("ids").alias("ids"))
```

The output is like:

```
+-----------+--------------------+
|      genre|                 ids|
+-----------+--------------------+
|      Crime|[[6, 22], [6, 42]...|
|    Romance|[[3, 7], [3, 11],...|
|   Thriller|[[6, 10], [6, 16]...|
|  Adventure|[[2, 8], [2, 10],...|
|   Children|[[1, 2], [1, 8], ...|
|      Drama|[[4, 11], [4, 14]...|
|        War|[[41, 110], [41, ...|
|Documentary|[[37, 77], [37, 9...|
|    Fantasy|[[2, 56], [2, 60]...|
|    Mystery|[[59, 113], [59, ...|
+-----------+--------------------+
```

However, what would be the equivalent when writing the function in `pandas udf`.

PS: I understand, alternatively, I can use cross-join to achieve the same results.

But, I am more curious about how do pandas udf handle column with ArrayType.

Comment: maybe something like `lambda row: row.apply(lambda x: itertools.combinations(x, 2))`

Comment: thanks, @mck, that was one of my attempts. 
now I think the issue I have is more related to `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: sun.misc.Unsafe or java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int) not available`. after a few google search, it seems to do with java 11 and spark-arrow support. which may belong to a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to share my findings here:

there are 3 aspects in order to make pandas udf work for your project:

#### 1. pandas UDF, or more precisely, Apache Arrow does not support complex types as common udf does.(as of `pyspark 3.0.1`, `pyarrow 2.0.0`)

e.g.:

- `ArrayType(StringType())` is supported by pandas udf.
- `ArrayType(StructType([...]))` are NOT supported.
  you can check out more: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#supported-sql-types

#### 2. if you are running Java 11, which is the default in (py)Spark 3. you need to add the following as part of your spark config:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true'
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true'
```

this will solve the `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` mentioned above.

#### 3. make sure your virtual environment python path is added to your `pyspark_python`

i.e.
`environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON']='./your/virtual/enviroment/path'`